# Запятая перед "да"

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая перед "да"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставится в том случае, если "да" разделяет два простых предложения в составе сложного или употребляется в значении "но".

Answer (score 1):

Также когда употребляется в предложениях с однородными членами в значении сочинительного союза *и*: "На стол поставили блюдо с устрицами, да поросёнка, да фунта два сахару".

Answer (score 0):

В значении сочинительного союза перед "да" ставится запятая, только если союз повторяется